# Animate Search Navigation Controller like Music app Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uinavigationitem

I want to create a search like **Apple Music app** in my project.

In the **Apple Music app**, when you tap on the search icon, the **Tab Bar** is still there, but top **Navigation Item** is hidden by moving down the **Search Bar**.

I have a problem with adding a "move down animation" for **Search Bar**.

If I choose a **Present Modally Segue**, I can add animation like this, but **Tab Bar Controller** is hidden. In **Show Segue** first title animates too... (moving from center to left with fading out).

Please help in **Swift**!